# Micronaut session login code fails upon startup

Tags: security, session, micronaut

I am attempting to run a Micronaut server that is supposed to run session- based authentication. I am using the instructions provided at

https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-security-session/guide/index.html

Based on those instructions, I am using the following information in the application.yaml file:

```
micronaut:
   security:
     enabled: true 
     endpoints:
        login:
        enabled: true 
      logout:
        enabled: true 
    session:
      enabled: true 
      login-success-target-url: / 
      login-failure-target-url: /login/authFailed
```

I am also using the correct version of Micronaut (v1.1.0.M1) as specified in the instructions.

I run the Micronaut server and am getting the following failures:

```
22:07:58.212 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 3, column 6:
         enabled: true 
     ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
 in 'reader', line 7, column 7:
          logout:
      ^

org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 3, column 6:
         enabled: true 
     ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
 in 'reader', line 7, column 7:
          logout:
      ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:572)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:214)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:144)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:236)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:215)
          ...

        (Lines omitted for brevity)
```

Is there something missing here? These are the exact lines provided in the instructions! I am using the code for the session login example described in the Guide!

UPDATE:

I have used the validation application suggested by James:

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

to fix the formatting problems he mentioned in application.yaml. Apparently, YAML parsers are a little sensitive about tabs and spaces in YAML declarations. Retyping parts of the YAML file has produced the following file:

```
micronaut:
   security:
     enabled: true 
     endpoints:
        login:
           enabled: true 
        logout:
           enabled: true 
        session:
            enabled: true 
            login-success-target-url: / 
            login-failure-target-url: /login/authFailed
```

Please note the changes in spacing that were necessary to make the contents valid.

After fixing the formatting problems, I now have a "valid" YAML file that, when I run Micronaut, now generates the following errors:

```
10:06:56.253 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 11, column 37:
                login-success-target-url: / 
                                    ^

org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 11, column 37:
                login-success-target-url: / 
                                    ^

at  org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchValue(ScannerImpl.java:870)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:358)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:558)
              ...
           (Lines omitted for brevity)
```

This shows the following:

1. That there is at least one error in the guide provided for setting up session- based login for a Micronaut microservice, because the entire YAML file is line- for- line the same as the one described in the guide! The code as described in the guide simply cannot work because of these parsing failures in the YAML file!
2. That the information currently in this guide cannot be relied upon for accuracy, and that corrections need to be made to it in order to make its code work properly.
3. That in general, even ignoring the fact that the quide provided bad information on the login URL configurations, using YAML to configure the microservice is extremely error prone (due to the ease at which formatting errors can be made), and probably is not the most practical format for configuring a microservice (or anything else, for that matter).

Can someone provide a proper configuration syntax for those login-success and login-failure URLs, or some other proper configuration lines that will tell the microservice where to go on login success of failure? Or (preferably) can someone provide an example of a micronaut session- based login service that actually works???

Answer (score 2):

Your yaml file is not formatted properly. You can use an online validator to get instant feedback on any errors. For example https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator